# fscanf doesnt work properly

Tags: c, file-io, multiprocessing, scanf

hi there a have an assignment on multiprocess programming and i'm facing with a problem when i try to read characters line by line (each line consists of 3 character and 1 integer). the problem is when i use `fscanf` it doesnt work properly and it reads the characters successfully just in every 2 steps. here you can see my code;

```
#include <stdio.h>     /* basic I/O routines.   */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>    /* define fork(), etc.   */
#include <sys/types.h> /* define pid_t, etc.    */
#include <sys/wait.h>  /* define wait(), etc.   */
#include <signal.h>    /* define signal(), etc. */
#include <pthread.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void child_process(int);
void parent_process();
void function();
int counter=0;
int bond_number=0;

char* f_strand;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    counter = atoi(argv[1]);

    function();

    fflush(stdout);

    execl("/usr/bin/killall","killall","tail",(char *) 0);
    return 0;
}

void function(){

    int i,k;
    pid_t child_pid[counter];
    char array[counter];
    char array_opst[counter];
    srand ( time(NULL) );
    int temp;

    FILE* fptr;
    fptr = fopen("sample.txt","w");

    if(! (f_strand=(char*)malloc(counter*sizeof(char))) ){
        printf("Error\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    for(i=0; i<counter; i++){

        temp = rand()%4;

        if(temp==0){
            *(f_strand+i) = 'A';
            fprintf(fptr,"A\n");
        }
        else if(temp==1){
            *(f_strand+i) = 'C';
            fprintf(fptr,"C\n");
        }
        else if(temp==2){
            *(f_strand+i) = 'T';
            fprintf(fptr,"T\n");
        }
        else if(temp==3){
            *(f_strand+i) = 'G';
            fprintf(fptr,"G\n");
        }
    }

    fclose(fptr);

                    for (i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
                      if ( (child_pid[i] = fork() ) < 0) {

                        perror("fork");
                        abort();
                      } 
                      else if (child_pid[i] == 0) {

                        child_process(i);
                        exit(0);
                      }
                    }
    int status;
    pid_t pid;
    int num=counter;
        while (num > 0) {
          pid = wait(&status);
          //printf("Child with PID %ld exited with status 0x%x.\n", (long)pid, status);
          --num;  // Remove pid from the pids array.
        }


    parent_process();
    printf("\n");

}

void child_process(int index){

    int i;
    char str,str1,str2;

    FILE* fptr;
    fptr = fopen("sample.txt","r");

    fseek (fptr, 2*index, SEEK_SET);
    fscanf(fptr,"%c", &str);

    FILE* fptr2;
    fptr2 = fopen("sample_2.txt","a");

       if( str == 'A' ){
            str1='T';
            str2=';';
            fprintf(fptr2,"%c%c%c%d\n",str,str2,str1,index);
            }
       else if( str == 'T' ){
            str1='A';
            str2=';';
            fprintf(fptr2,"%c%c%c%d\n",str,str2,str1,index);
            }
       else if( str == 'G' ){
            str1='C';
            str2=':';
            fprintf(fptr2,"%c%c%c%d\n",str,str2,str1,index);
            }
       else if( str == 'C' ){
            str1='G';
            str2=':';
            fprintf(fptr2,"%c%c%c%d\n",str,str2,str1,index);
            }

    fflush(stdout);
    fclose(fptr);
    fclose(fptr2);
    sleep(1);

}

void parent_process(void){

    FILE* fptr;
    fptr = fopen("sample_2.txt","r");

    char str,str1,str2;
    int index,i,k;
    char array_opst[counter]; //  second strand
    char array_type[counter]; // bond type

    i=0;

    while( !feof(fptr) ){

        if(4==fscanf(fptr,"%c%c%c%d",&str,&str1,&str2,&index)){

            if(feof(fptr))
                break;

            printf("STR = %c\n, K = %d",str,k);

            array_type[index]=str1;
            array_opst[index]=str2;
            printf("WHILE\n");

            if(array_type[index] == ':')
                bond_number=bond_number+2;
            else if(array_type[index] == ';')
                bond_number=bond_number+3;
    }

        i++;
}
    fclose(fptr);

}
```

this is the output of sample2.txt

```
C:G5
G:C6
A;T4
C:G3
G:C7
C:G8
G:C2
A;T9
T;A1
C:G0
```

in the `parent_process()` it tries to read 3 characters and one integer line by line from `sample2.txt` file. but it does this process in every two lines. i mean it reads first third fifth lines and goes on. i will be appreciated if you can help and thanks anyway.

Comment: Can you create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) with a `sample2.txt` file that demonstrates this behavior?

Comment: Something tells me that `fscanf()` probably works fine.

Comment: Have you tried using a lower-level input routine, such as `fgets` or even `read`?  `fscanf` is almost always more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: @oldrinb hey there i deleted some unusefull parts and added the output of sample2.txt

Comment: @Zack i didnt try `fgets` cause i'm not taking the line as a whole string. i guess if i read as a line i have to parse the string.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I mean about fscanf being more trouble than it's worth.  It *promises* to let you avoid writing your own parser, but in my experience it always winds up being easier to read line by line and then parse by hand.  oldrinb's answer illustrates one of the ways this is the case.

Comment: why do you use `f_strand`?  You are building a string without a `\0`-terminating bytes, this could end wrong. And `sizeof char` is 1. Call `malloc` in this way: `if_strand=malloc(counter * sizeof *if_strand)`. This is much safer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an interesting multifaceted issue. The first thing to note is that you're using the `c` conversion. The C99 standard states as follows (§7.19.6.2¶8).

> Input white-space characters (as specified by the `isspace` function) are skipped, unless
>   the specification includes a `[`, `c`, or `n` specifier.

Now, let's take a look at the important line.

> ```
>     if(4==fscanf(fptr,"%c%c%c%d",&str,&str1,&str2,&index)){
> ```

What occurs is that whitespace (the padding between the entries, the line terminator, etc.) is being consumed by `fscanf`. When this occurs, the read is misaligned such that it fails to read an integer when encountering the `d` conversion. As a result, `fscanf` does not evaluate to `4`, the branch is not taken and thus the incorrectly read data isn't printed.

Instead, it requires incorrectly reading every other line to 'realign' to the proper input and thus you only see these select lines printed. To evidence this, try replacing the condition with merely `0 < fscanf(...)` and the incorrect reads will produce the output to demonstrate the intermediate attempts at reading every other line.

Comment: this is an explanatory reply thanks for it. it works when i try to read `\n`  as a character with `if(5==fscanf(fptr,"%c%c%c%d%c",&str,&str1,&str2,&index,&nl))`

Answer (score 2):

I assume the problem is the newline character. Try include it into the format string or read an extra char in-between consecutive fscanf() calls.

Comment: +1 [Input white-space characters (as specified by `isspace()`) shall be skipped, unless the conversion specification includes a `[`, `c`, `C`, or `n` conversion specifier.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/scanf.html)